# How to add authentication to multiple routes in Remix js effciently?

Tags: remix

On top every route (page) in Remix that needs the user to be logged in, I have to copy and paste this code:

```js
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({request}) => {
    const email = await authenticator.isAuthenticated(request, {
        failureRedirect: "/login",
    });
    return email;
}
```

Is there a non-repetitive way of doing this? Some sort of decorator, like in other languages? `[Authentication]`

Comment: Related question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75135576/remix-authentication-and-nested-route-loaders